# How to access files which are not in public folder in next js

Tags: javascript, next.js, file-upload

I am working on a next js project and I am storing files in the root directory of the project `/uploads/qr/myimage.png`. How do I access that file in that project. I tried to make a route `/api/getImg/route.js` which will serve image files and I write this code on there

```js
import fs from 'fs';
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import path from 'path';

export async function GET(req) {
  const { searchParams } = new URL(req.url);
        const id = searchParams.get("id");
  const imagePath = path.join(process.cwd(), 'uploads', 'qr', `${id}.png`);

  try {
    const data = fs.readFileSync(imagePath);
    return NextResponse.send(data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    return NextResponse.send('Image not found');
  }
}
```

but it gives me error

`next_dist_server_web_exports_next_response__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.default.send is not a function`

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out. Just need to send the response in different way.

```js
import fs from 'fs';
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import path from 'path';

export async function GET(req) {
    const { searchParams } = new URL(req.url);
    const id = searchParams.get("id");
    try {
        // Read the image file from the uploads/qr directory
        const imagePath = path.join(process.cwd(), 'uploads', 'qr', `${id}.png`);
        const fileContents = fs.readFileSync(imagePath);

        return new NextResponse(fileContents, { status: 200, headers: new Headers({  "content-type": "image/png", }) })
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error serving image:', error);
        return NextResponse.json(error)
    }
}
```